# How to know whether a set of points can be rotated to lie in positive orthant?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, linear-transformations, dynamical-systems, rotations

I have a set of points in N-dimensional space. I want to find out whether they could, in principle, be rotated to lie solely in the positive orthant of space. Is there a property of these points that would guarantee this rotation exists?

If this question proves too difficult, perhaps another related one will be easier. I have the linear dynamical system and starting point that generated these points. Is there a property of linear dynamical systems which, if satisfied, ensure that under some rotation the trajectory will lie solely in the positive orthant?

To give an idea of the kind of thing I'm looking for (if it exists!): in 2D if the dot products between the set of points are all positive you can guarantee that there's some rotation that could rotate the set of points into the positive quadrant, and if a dot product is negative you know there is no such rotation. This is a nice easy test I can apply. However, this approach doesn't generalise (in 3D points can have all positive dot products, but cannot be rotated into the positive octant), can you think of one that will generalise?

**Later edit - a few things I've been considering:**

People study positive linear systems: linear dynamical systems, $\dot{\boldsymbol{x}}(t) = \boldsymbol{Ax}(t)$, in which the trajectory, $\boldsymbol{x}(t)$, never leaves the positive orthant. It turns out if the matrix $\boldsymbol{A}$ is Metzler, meaning all off-diagonal elements are non-negative, then a trajectory starting in the positive orthant will stay there. This is related to the Perron-Frobenius Theorem which I don't know so much about.

So it seems another way of framing my question would be: you have your linear dynamical system in an arbitrary basis. Can you tell whether the dynamics matrix $\boldsymbol{A}$ is Metzler under some rotation? The Perron-Frobenius theorem talks about rotation invariant things like eigenvalue spectra which gives me hope that this could be a constructive route, but I haven't been able to fit things together yet... Maybe the clever people on this site will be able to!

(Which is similar to this old question: [Converse of Perron Frobenius Theorem: Necessary and Sufficient Conditions for positivity (or non negativity)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1170746/converse-of-perron-frobenius-theorem-necessary-and-sufficient-conditions-for-po))

Comment: Maybe given a vector with N entries you could take pairs of entries and take the dot product with the formed pairs? Given a pair of entries, if all dot products with respect to this pair are positive, then you may rotate the vectors in this pair of entries to turn them all positive, now you take a different pair and repeat the process. If for all pairs of entries, the 2-dimensional dot product is positive for all vectors then you can turn all entries positive by composing rotations. Not sure if this would be good enough for you.

Comment: That's a good idea @AmadeusMaldonado, my only worry is how we choose the axes. Perhaps in some basis this 2-dims at a time procedure will work, but if the basis we have doesn't line up with the one in which the points can be placed in the positive quadrant, then I think this might get stuck...

Comment: It is interesting that in dimension $N$, any cone with cone angle (between axis & generator) more than $\approx \frac{1}{\sqrt N}$ cannot fit into the first orthant.

Comment: For a set of points in $\mathrm R^2$ to lie in a quadrant given only rotations about the origin of coordinates, then the angle subtended at the origin by any two points of the set must be less than $π/2.$ In $\mathrm R^3,$ the solid angle subtended at the origin by any three points of the set must be less than the angle between the three coordinate axes defining an octant. In general, in space of $n$ dimensions, the angle subtended at the origin by any $n$ points of the set must be less than the angle defined by the $n$ coordinate axes defining an orthant.

Comment: @Allawonder that is a good point, and is in principle the answer to my question. However, it appears that solid angles in higher dimensions are very difficult to calculate, see for example this paper: https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2Fs00454-006-1253-4.pdf
Which I found on this old question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/202261/solid-angle-between-vectors-in-n-dimensional-space
Though I haven't strenuously tried to use the results in that linked paper, perhaps it is do-able?

Comment: @WillDorrell One way to avoid angles is as follows. Define the diameter of a set of points in $\mathrm R^n$ to be the supremum of $|x-y|,$ where $x,y$ belong in the set and $|\cdot|$ defines an appropriate metric in the space. Then for your set to lie in an orthant, it is enough that the centre of your set (the midpoint of the diameter, that is) should be farther from the coordinate hyperplanes than from any point in the set. Or in other words, the radius (half the diameter) of your set should be less than the radius of the concentric ball tangential to the coordinate hyperplanes.

Answer (score 1):

Not a solution but some simple comments rather. 
First off, one can normalize vectors $x_k$ i.e. multiply them by a positive scalar so that we can assume that $||x_k||$ = 1.
Then we look for a unitary operator, say $U$ such that $U(x_k)$ has non-negative coordinates  for any $k \in \{1,2,....m\}$.
If such $U$ can be found then for any subset $S \subset \{1,2,...,m\}$ we would have
$$||\sum_{k \in S} U(x_k)|| >= (\sum_{k \in S} ||U(x_k)||)^{\frac{1}{2}} $$
I mean, $||.||$ here is assumed to be Euclidean i.e. $l_2$ norm and for such norms it is not difficult to see that the above inequality holds (again $U(x_k)$ has nonnegative coordinates). Since $U$ is unitary we can now formulate necessary condition for the set of (normalized) points to be rotated into positive orthant:
$$||\sum_{k \in S} x_k|| >= \sqrt |S| $$
for any subset $S \subset \{1,2,...,m\}$

It is easy to see that this conditions is also sufficient in $R^{1}$ and $R^{2}$.

For n=1 it means that all vectors point in the same direction, and for n=2 we just take two vectors with the biggest angle between them and the condition above insures that this angle is not bigger than $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: Thank you for this! I'm currently trying to prove to myself that the inequality you suggest holds, but I've also been thinking:
I have an example to consider. Imagine the n = 1 case, so the $x_k$ are all +1 or -1. You could have 5 points, 4 at +1 and 1 at -1, then $||\sum_k x_k|| = 3 \geq \sqrt{5}$, so we can see that in 1D this condition is not sufficient since all the points do not point in the same direction.


However if the condition was not square root S, but just S it would be sufficient in 1D. Just a thought.

Comment: No it is sufficient since in your case if you take 1 and -1 vectors the sum is $0$ and clearly it is not >= $\sqrt2$. This inequality has to hold for ALL  subset.

Comment: Ah sorry yes, I had missed the ALL subsets thing, thanks for the correction!